# Search by JSON field not working in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, postgresql

This is "tags" field as json in products table:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Adidas","slug":"adidas"},{"id":2,"name":"Nike","slug":"nike"}]
```

In Eloquent, I used query:

```
$query->whereJsonContains('tags->slug', 'adidas');
```

But no results are returned.

How can I search by tag's slug in products table with Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use get();

> $query->whereJsonContains('tags->slug', 'adidas')->get();